# Starting the timer with click of any button

Tags: swift, timer

var nsTimer = NSTimer()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.nsTimer.invalidate()
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     nsTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("updatetime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}

func updateTime() {
    counter = counter + 0.1
    timer.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter) + "s"
}
```

any one know about that ?
when i click on any button timer starting and when i click to the another button timer contains

Comment: Add an appropriate tag suggesting a programming language of your interest. Is it Objective-c? Tag as such, if it is the case.

Comment: Start the timer on viewDidAppear or in any other event which gets executed after the UI has been loaded

Comment: my program language is swift

Comment: I want my timer started when i touch any where on my game or touch any button how can i make it?

Comment: Do you know how to start a timer at all? Then, do you know how to start the timer on click of a specific button? Then you can use a reference of that timer in the event handler of every one of these buttons.

Comment: yes i know but i have the memory matches game .... i have 16 button (cards) when i started the game i want to click to any button my timer is started and after click to anther card my timer contains

Comment: @gina timers where meant to update the UI not to measure time. You should just save the date (start time) and calculate time interval since that date. The timer shouldn't be fired more than 30x per second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an IBAction and link all you buttons to it.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
//this will check if your timer is running if not the start the timer, if the timer is already running do nothing and keep timer running 
 if !nsTimer.Enabled {
   nsTimer.Start()
   } 
 }
```

Make sure to connect all you buttons to this method and remove your code from touchesBegan

Comment: Yup that was my bad, just updated the answer. This should work I am sorry I don't have access to a computer at the moment so I can't test the code but the above should work

Comment: ok thank you so much i make it but without if and i put (nsTimer.invalidate).

Comment: gina i just got to my computer i have edited the answer and it should solve all your problems. if my answer helped you please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is starting because your triggering the event from touchesBegan which will start if there is any touch on the view.
If you want to start the timer from a uibutton I suggest you trigger the timer from an @IBAction associated with the a button. Now if you insist on keeping the timer within the touchesBegan you need some logic so start the trigger the timer instead of being triggered with every touch in the view

Comment: OK but what is this logic that i need it?

Comment: yes   i want timer starting with first touch on any button

Comment: Do you want the timer to keep on running if it was running already when a button is touched ? Or to reset ??

Comment: ya i want the timer to keep when i touch another button

Comment: in my program i have more than button ...... i want when i click on any button timer is starting after click on another one timer keep to contains

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an IBAction and link all you buttons to it.

@IBAction func buttontapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !nsTimer.valid {  check if timer starting or not 
        nsTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:Selector("updateTime"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
        }

Make sure to connect all you buttons to this method and remove your code from touchesBegan

Comment: Gina I gave you this answer....you just re-wrote it and accepted it as an answer...that is very unprofessional

Comment: i am sorry but iam don't know how to use this account exatly